# memcpy overlapping not understandable

Tags: c, memcpy

I'm playing with `memcpy` in order to acquire better perception of its work and i've run into things i can't understand.

I start from very simple piece of code:

```
char str [] = "0123456789abcdef";
memcpy(str + 5, str, 5);
puts(str);// prints 0123401234abcdef
```

that's absolutely understandable for me. Then i move on:

```
char str [] = "0123456789abcdef";
memcpy(str + 5, str, 6);
puts(str); // 01234012340bcdef
```

at first i expected the output to be `01234012345bcdef` assuming that the function will take first six characters but it started from 0 again. Ok, thought i, probably it somehow takes characters from already built new string. And putting 7 like this `memcpy(str + 5, str, 7);` confirmed this my assumption because it had produced `012340123401cdef` as output.

But then things started to get more unclear. If i do this `memcpy(str + 5, str, 8);` it outputs `0123401234567def`!!!. Just like i expected from the beginning.

I'm totally confused. Why it behaves this way? Ok, i can even understand printing 01 as 11th and 12th characters of the string (but this is not what i expected and i would be grateful for an explanation). But why when i determine the length as 8 it changes its behaviour???

I hope you understand what i mean. Please provide a detailed explanation. Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: The reason why it changes behavior at 8 is probably because the code uses word operations on groups of 4 bytes, and then operates on the remaining bytes one at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [The memcpy() function shall copy n bytes from the object pointed to by s2 into the object pointed to by s1. If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/memcpy.html)

`memcpy` assumes that the source and destination don't overlap. If they do, anything can happen, and exactly what happens may depend on what compiler you use, what machine you compile or run on, how big the region you're copying is, what time of day it is, etc. If you want to copy a block of memory to a destination overlapping the original position, use `memmove`.

Answer (score 0):

For [**`memcpy()`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy):

> [...] If the objects overlap, the behavior is **undefined**.

You should use [**`memmove()`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memmove) instead for overlapping cases.

> [...] The objects may overlap: copying takes place as if the characters were copied to a temporary character array and then the characters were copied from the array to dest.

Comment: There's no `std::` in C, that's C++.